# Return requests on multiple lines in email form

Tags: php, email

Hi i have this PHP email that i'm using; I'd like to get the email output to present the requested data on multiple likes like

```
name
company name
phone number
email
address
comments
```

instead of how i get the email currently

```
$message = 'Name: '.$name.', Company: '.$company.', Phone: '.$phone.', Mailing Address: '.$mailing_address.'From: '.$email_address.', Message: '.$comments;
```

i'm a php noob any help would be great!

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "you@hotmail.com"; /* ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS TO THE LEFT INSIDE THE QUOTES */

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "index.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$company = $_REQUEST['company'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$mailing_address = $_REQUEST['mailing_address'];
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;
$message = 'Name: '.$name.', Company: '.$company.', Phone: '.$phone.', Mailing Address: '.$mailing_address.'From: '.$email_address.', Message: '.$comments;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($name)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Maxbulb Inquiry from: $name", $message);
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @kimbarcelona is thinking of web display, not email. 
I use this and it works for me:

```
$message = "There has been an order for Learning Fundamentals on $curDateTime\n\n";
        $message .= "$name\n";
        $message .= "$company\n";

        $message .= "$street1\n";
        $message .= "$street2\n";
        $message .= "$city, $state $province $zip\n";
        $message .= "$country\n";
```

I like the .= notation in PHP because it make things easier to read. If you don‘t want to change your code, you can add the newlines before each new header, like this:

```
$message = 'Name: '.$name.',\nCompany: '.$company.',\nPhone: '.$phone.',\nMailing Address: '.$mailing_address.'From: '.$email_address.',\nMessage: '.$comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
 $message = 'Name: '.$name.'
    \n Company: '.$company.'
    \n Phone: '.$phone.'
    \n Mailing Address: '.$mailing_address.'
    \n From: '.$email_address.'
    \n Message: '.$comments;
```

Comment: sort of worked but i can see the <br> code in my email